# Geany IDE in windows 7-Getting an error when executing C program

Tags: c

When I'm trying to execute C language program after successful compilation, I am getting an error in console window. My program's name is `first1programm.c`.

Here is the code of the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{    
    printf("Hello world")
    return 0;   
}
```

The error message is:

```
 Error '".first 1 program"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Please show the command that you execute on the command line

Comment: after changing name getting this error failed to excute ""./hello""{start-script could not be created}

Comment: @david Heffernan i m executing it through Geany IDE not through command line.

Comment: are you using cygwin gcc?

Comment: semi-colon after printf() ?

Comment: missing semicolon after `printf("Hello world")`

Comment: If you are using gcc with geany IDE,try compiling and running it using gcc and command line without the IDE

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the path doesn't include the directory you're in.  Try adding to your path

PATH=.;%PATH%

Comment: C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Geany\bin; i have ADDED this path still getting same error i have java jdk also install on my pc does is this aproblem.

Comment: No it can't be `java` problem, you missed ";" after `printf` and I am not sure but you should put space after `#include <stdio.h>`.To compile your program use: `gcc name.c -o name`
to run program use: `./name`*EDIT:* Space after include is optional.